# How can i use component from lazy loaded module as child in other component which is not lazy loaded?

Tags: angular

I have one lazy loaded module.Part of that module is CreateEmployeeComponent.I have also home component which is not lazy loaded,it's route path is defined in the app-routing.module.ts file.When i try to use the CreateEmployeeComponent as child in the Home component i get error 
app-create-employee is not a known element which is expected because app.module.ts dont know nothing about that CreateEmployeeComponent is declared in the declarations array in my EmployeeModule.If i dont use lazy loading i will insert the EmployeeModule in the app.module.ts file and the error will be fixed.I can't insert now EmployeeModule in my app.module.ts because then he will not be lazy loaded.

How can i solve this problem?

```
//app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path:'employees' , data: {preload:true}, loadChildren:'./modules/employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];


//employee-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [

    { path: '', component: ListEmployeesComponent },
    { path: 'create', component: CreateEmployeeComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: CreateEmployeeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EmployeeRoutingModule { }


//employee.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EmployeeRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CreateEmployeeComponent,
    ListEmployeesComponent,
    CompoWithChildrensComponent,
    ChildrenOneComponent,
    ChildrenTwoComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    CreateEmployeeComponent
  ]
})
export class EmployeeModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `AppModule` uses a component from `EmployeeModule`, you have to import `EmployeeModule`.

You can split `EmployeeModule` in two modules; one module with `CreateEmployeeComponent` and one module with the rest. You can than import the first module and lazy load the second.

You have to determine for yourself if this is practical and useful for your app.